# Functional tests with Jersey Test, Grizzly and HK2 Dependency Injection

Tags: java, unit-testing, jersey-2.0, hk2, jersey-test-framework

I'm attempting to write functional tests for my REST API using the Jersey Test framework. However, I've seem to hit a roadblock when it comes to using dependency injection within my functional tests. My main application looks like this:

```
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class Application extends ResourceConfig {

    private static final URI BASE_URI = URI.create("http://localhost:8080/api/");

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Starting application...");

        final ServiceLocator locator = ServiceLocatorUtilities.createAndPopulateServiceLocator();

        final ResourceConfig resourceConfig = new ResourceConfig();
        resourceConfig.register(JacksonFeature.class);
        resourceConfig.register(LoggingFeature.class);
        resourceConfig.packages(true, "my.package.name");

        final HttpServer server = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(BASE_URI, resourceConfig, locator);

        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(server::shutdownNow));

        server.start();

        Thread.currentThread().join();
    }
}
```

Notice here that I'm using the HK2's `ServiceLocatorUtilities.createAndPopulateServiceLocator()` method in order to read the `hk2-metadata-generator` file. This method creates a `ServiceLocator` object which then in turn is passed to the `GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer` method. This all works great for running the Grizzly server, however, the question I have now is how do I create functional tests for my application with the Jersey Test Framework?

My unit test currently looks like this:

```
public class FormsResourceTest extends JerseyTest {

    @Override
    protected TestContainerFactory getTestContainerFactory() throws TestContainerException {
        return new GrizzlyWebTestContainerFactory();
    }

    @Test
    public void testMe() {
        Response response = target("/test").request().get();
        assertEquals("Should return status 200", 200, response.getStatus());
    }

}
```

Is there even a way to use the HK2 service locator with the Jersey Test framework or do I need to treat my application as an external container and use the external container provider as documented here: [External container](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/test-framework.html#d0e17582)?

Also, since these are functional tests, mocking the injected services is not an option here.

Comment: Why can't you use AbstractBinder to bind your dependencies (interface to impl) and then register the binder to ResourceConfig and pass ResourceConfig to the server?

Comment: @Raf That's actually the direction I ended up going. I figured out that's it's better to be explicitly declare my dependencies instead of scanning the packages to find them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Locator Bridge](https://hk2.java.net/2.5.0-b06/extensibility.html#ServiceLocator_to_ServiceLocator_Bridge) to take two separate locator (the one you created and the one from Jersey) and bridge them together.  The bridge can be made bi-directional as well (within limits) and so it'll appear in most normal usage to be one large ServiceLocator.

Note that there was a bug fixed this week with the ServiceLocator bridge which has not yet been pushed out to maven but will (probably) be pushed sometime next week.  See [HK2-295](https://java.net/jira/browse/HK2-295)